# What is the generic name for fonts that have words in them?

Tags: tools, font, names, style

Is there a generic name given to fonts like this? I would also like to know if they are hand made or generated by an application.

[image: Screen shot of NE. Both letters made of other words]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a "word cloud" or "tag cloud". I dont know if there are any fonts to make it. But you can do it with many webtools (such as [wordie](http://www.wordle.net/)) or better you can render it manually using Adobe Illustrator or InkScape.